# How deploying an IOS Application for BTB

Tags: ios, iphone

I am company A. I develop an IOS application (iPhone) for company B. Company B will give the possibility to download it (free) to another company :

- a company C with 4 employees.
- a company D with 1 employee.
  Etc.

If I understand , the following solutions are possible:

**1- Creating a standard developer account and submitting the application.**

I think the application will not be validated by Apple because :
- you must authenticate to access it.
- It is not possible to subscribe directly to the application. The access codes are communicated by e-mail by company B.

**2- Creating a standard developer account and submitting the application in BTB mode and Creating an account "Volume Purchase Program" for the company B.**

With this solution the validation of the application by Apple has more chance.
I ask myself these questions :

- How is the application distributed to companies C and D?
- Every company wanting the application, must register with a "Volume Purchase Program" account?
- If so, Apple has not imagined another way because this process is cumbersome for small company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the on-boarding process Apple will generally accept apps like this in the App Store. Company C uses Company B's services, they can download your app and login if they have credentials. A random person downloading the app will just be presented with a login screen, and that is fine.

You can even load in specific Company C & D branding, since when an employee logs in you should know what company they are attached too. This is extremely common.

One thing to note. Apps that are free in the App Store, funded via other means (e.g. BTB subscription), will generally be questioned by Apple. They want to know if you are trying to be sneaky and intentionally bypassing their payment models. So from personal experience, expect to be rejected the first time, pending you answer a few questions. But ultimately, you shouldn't have any pressing issues.